# Encontrar pacote npm não utilizado em package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, dependências

Existe alguma maneira de encontrar pacotes (packages) no seu package.json que não estão sendo utilizados pela aplicação?

Por enquanto eu busco nome por nome do pacote e vejo se ele está rendo importado na aplicação.

Teria um caminho mais eficiente de deletar esses pacotes de maneira segura?

Comment: Já pensou usar o pacote [`depcheck`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck)? Ela faz uma análise de pacotes usados, o tamanho, quais pacotes são inutilizados, quais estão faltando, etc... Ao meu ver é a maneira mais rápida e confiável que eu uso em meus projetos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe sim, a biblioteca depcheck é uma ferramenta para analisar as dependências de seu projeto, ela tem diversas funções, dentre elas a análise de bibliotecas que não estão sendo utilizadas.

1. Execute o depcheck com o npx

```sh
npx depcheck
```

Caso queira uma análise mais complexa é possível instalar o depcheck em seu projeto, configura-lo e integra-lo com serviços de integração contínua.